# how to take screenshot with Paint event (WM_Paint) in QT

Tags: c++, qt

i'm trying to take screenshot with Paint event (WM_Paint) event in QT but i dont know how,
i used this code to take screenshot but it is not really good for do this
it must do screenshot when some changes in desktop not take screenshot every 1000 ms with timer

```
     void MainWindow::shootScreen()
 {
 originalPixmap = QPixmap(); // clear image for low memory situations
                             // on embedded devices.

 originalPixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());

 //emit getScreen(originalPixmap);

 updateScreenshotLabel();

 }

 void MainWindow::updateScreenshotLabel()
 {
     this->ui->label_2->setPixmap(originalPixmap.scaled(this->ui->label_2-    >size(),
                                                  Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                                  Qt::SmoothTransformation));
 }
```

Comment: Can you not emit a signal from the controls on UI that you are keen about. Like, if you want to take a screenshot when the text in a textbox changes, or image in an image control changes, just create a custom  control and emit a signal when the contents of the control changes. And from the slot, capture the screen shot? If you are doing that in paint, too many scenarios will fire paint, so screenshot will be taken unnecessarily.

Comment: The easiest solution is to install an event filter on the objects of interest.

Comment: What things are you taking screenshots of? If it's the entire desktop, then there's no cross-platform way in Qt to monitor its updates; you have to read up on how it's done on each platform. Anyway, whatever is the native representation of a screen on Windows obviously doesn't get paint events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`QObject::installEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the widgets you are interested in, then check for the proper events. For example, in your `MainWindow` ui initialization:

```
void MainWindow::yourUiInitFunc()
{
    exampleWidget = new QWidget;
    ...
    exampleWidget->installEventFilter(this);
    ...
}
```

Then re-implement `eventFilter`:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == exampleWidget && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        shootScreen();
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: **Watch out** -- change that `return false` to `return BaseClass::eventFilter(obj, event)` or you're likely to break whatever class you're inhering from!

Answer (score 0):

tank you Jon Harper your codes was useful but i changed somethings there
your code just work when some key press event on my project form but i added paint method to your if and now it work on windows events too

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{

    if (obj == this && QEvent::Paint == event->type()) {
        shootScreen();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: There's very little point at installing an event filter on *yourself*, just override `event` for that.